# Merge two column

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

Please help me in crystal report.

eg:-

val 1, val 2

I want like:-

val 1 and 2

Answer (score 1):

Insert a text box, then drag the fields into the textbox that you want to merge.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of merging the fields in Crystal Reports, you could just do it in SQL when you select your data source:

```
select Column1 + ' and ' + Column2 
from YourTable
```

Or are the columns numeric?
If yes, the query will fail because SQL Server tries to add ' and ' to the numeric values.
In this case, you need to convert the columns to strings:

```
select cast(Column1 as nvarchar(100)) + ' and ' + cast(Column2 as nvarchar(100))
from YourTable
```